# How can I rotate a base64 image in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a json source that contains base64 images, and I would like to display them all in portrait. I think I need to build an array of Image objects, and rotate them as I build the array, but I'm not sure how to display the image objects in the view.

This is the array I've built

```
angular.forEach($scope.trayDetails.tray_images, function(trayImage) {
    var myBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+trayImage.data;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = myBase64;
    if (img.width>img.height ) {
        $(img).css({
            'transform': "rotate(90deg)"
        });
    }
    $scope.savedPictures.push(img);
});
```

But now I'm not sure what to do with the array, I tried these 2 methods with no luck

```
<li ng-repeat="savedPicture in savedPictures" class="photo">
    {{savedPicture}}
</li>

<li ng-repeat="savedPicture in savedPictures" class="photo">
    <img ng-src="{{savedPicture}}" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easier than you think:

```
angular.forEach($scope.trayDetails.tray_images, function(trayImage) {
   var myBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+trayImage.data;
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = myBase64;
   img.isRotated = img.width > img.height; //Use css class to rotate
   $scope.savedPictures.push(img);
});
```

Then add the img into html,:

```
<li ng-repeat="savedPicture in savedPictures" class="photo">
     <img ng-class="{rotateImg: savedPicture.isRotated}" ng-src="{{savedPicture.src}}" />
</li>
```

The img tags will have `rotateImg` class if its width is greater than its height. The css for `rotateImg` class is:

```
.rotateImg : { transform: rotate(90deg); }
```